# filter feeds containing a similar hashtag using django-taggi

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have the django-taggi library which is related to the user feed, I need to generate the filter by tags according to the library in an example of the documentation is done in this way.

```
  Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["delicious"])
    [<Food: apple>, <Food: pear>, <Food: plum>]
```

Model Feed:

```
    class Feed(UUIDModel, TimeStampedModel, mongo_models.Model, TaggitManager):
    #Other fields

    class TaggitManager:
        hashtags = TaggableManager(through=UUIDTaggedItem)
    
        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    class UUIDTaggedItem(GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
        pass
```

ViewSet

```
@extend_schema(description="", tags=["feed"])
class FeedViewSet(LPCDRModelViewSet):
    def _check_required_param(self, param_name):
        param_value = self.request.query_params.get(param_name)
        if not param_value:
            return exceptions.ValidationError(
                 {"error": f"params {param_name} is required"}
           )
        return None
    
    def get_queryset(self):  
        if self.action == "feed_hashtag_list":
          error = self._check_required_param("hashtag")
          if not error:
             return Feed.objects.filter(hashtags__name__in=["demo", "red"])
```

When we want to query or filter by a tag we get the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'hashtags' into field. Choices are: background, background_id, blocked, can_audio, can_be_shared_inside, can_be_shared_outside, can_commentary, can_download, can_duos, can_paste_video, comment_feeds, content, count_shared, created, draft, event, exclusive_adult_content, feed_event, feed_private, feed_type, finish_poll, friends_concrete, friends_concrete_id, friends_except, friends_except_id, id, is_announcement, link, link_external, mediafeed, modified, near, parent, parent_duos, parent_duos_feed, parent_duos_id, parent_feed, parent_id, programed, publish, questionfeed, reactions, reactions_feed_relation, reactions_id, special_announcement, sponsors, sponsors_id, state, state_id, time_to_programed, user, user_id, user_tags, user_tags_id`